# Can I exclude regional resources (e.g. values-fr) when building a particular Android Product Flavor with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Say I have this directory structure:

```
app
--src
   |--main
   |   |--java
   |   |--res
   |       |--drawable
   |       |--values
   |       |--values-fr
   |       |--values-de
   |
   |--flavor1
   |   |--res
   |       |--drawable
   |
   |--flavor2
   |   |--res
   |       |--drawable
   |
   |--flavor3
       |--res
           |--drawable
```

`values-fr` is common for both `flavor1` and `flavor2`, and so `values`, `values-fr` and `values-de` should get packaged

`flavor3` should only package `values` and `values-de`. So I need to exclude the `values-fr` resource folder from the `flavor3` only.

I've tried loads of combinations such as those below, but cannot figure it out, or even if it's possible.

```
sourceSets {
    flavor3 {
        res.exclude 'values-fr/**'
        res.exclude 'values-fr/'
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I found this working solution to **include** only German for the above example using:

```
productFlavors {
    flavour3 {
        resConfigs 'de' // include '-de' resources, along with default 'values'
    }
}
```

You can also check the list of country codes from ICU [here](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final working solution is to **include** a language - in this case, only German (de):

```
productFlavors {
    flavour3 {
        resConfigs 'de' // include '-de' resources, along with default 'values'
    }
}
```

As a reference, you can also check the list of country codes from ICU [here](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/).

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude those folders by using this snippet:

```
sourceSets {
  flavor3 {
    main {
      resources {
        srcDir 'res'
        exclude '**/values-fr/**'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work I'm afraid, even with `res` instead.