# excluding resources in flavors for API levels

Tags: android, android-resources, android-productflavors, android-api-levels

How can I exclude resource folders that contain resources for higher API Levels from my APK to keep its size minimal?

Currently I have PNG files in my drawable folder and WebP files with transparency (which are supported from API level 18) in drawable-v18. I have specified 2 flavors: One for newer APIs that make use of the drawable-v18 resources and one to support legacy devices lower than API 18.

```
flavorDimensions "api" 
productFlavors {
    common {
        dimension "api"
        minSdkVersion 18
    }

    legacy {
        dimension "api"
        maxSdkVersion 17 // This does not exclude the folders for higher APIs
    }
}
```

The *common* flavor correctly only contains the v18 drawables. But the *legacy* flavor contains both drawable and drawable-18. I thought specifying a maxSdkVersion would remove the v18 version, but that was not the fact.

How can I easily remove all resource configurations with API 18+ from my legacy flavor from within my gradle file?
Or do I need to put the drawables in the specific flavor folder (I want to avoid that)?

Comment: Maybe this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791469/can-i-exclude-regional-resources-e-g-values-fr-when-building-a-particular-and) is helpful ?

Comment: I already came across this post, but I think it does not work to easily exclude all higher API configurations with this approach.