# How to limit language support?

Tags: android, localization

I am currently working on the localisation of my app. I am supporting `en` for three different regions i.e USA(default language in app), Australia(`en-rAU`) and New Zealand(`en-rNZ`). Now I have created 3 `strings.xml` and stored them in their respective `values` folder. But in the current release of the app my boss wants me to show default language i.e `en-US` for the people who downloads the app in Australia . How can I load US english in Australia country with minimal changes at the app level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the strings files from resources for countries that you don't want support. Of course the default strings file should be in English.
Another way is use productFlavors from Gradle.
Here you can find an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791469/can-i-exclude-regional-resources-e-g-values-fr-when-building-a-particular-and)

And here is google [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Comment: I agree with you. just wanted to know is there any way to limit language support through gradle?

Comment: One doubt. I have `en` as the language for 3 different countries. How can I restrict it by region ?

Comment: use the suffix , for example "en-rNZ"

Comment: I tried your above solution. If I keep `resConfigs "en-rNZ"`, its only loading New Zealand `strings.xml`. how can I add the default `strings.xml` in this config ?